# How to validate the K8s secret is base64 encoded in helm diff command?

Tags: kubernetes, helm3

In the K8s secret manifest I put the secret at `data` field as non-base64 encoded secret. The `helm diff` execution works great and returns exit code `2` for diff. However for `helm upgrade` it failed exit code `1` because the secret `data` is not base64 encoded.

I would like to know if there is a way to verify at `helm diff` stage that the secret is non-base64 encoded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use secrets with helm you have 2 options. Either declare them with `stringData`, or use the `b64enc` function.

#### 1. StringData

[StringData](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#encoding-functions) does not have to be base64 encoded. In fact, it should not be encoded.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  password:  {{ .Values.password }}
```

#### 2. b64enc

Alternatively, [encode](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#encoding-functions) the raw string to base64.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
string:
  password: {{ .Values.password | b64enc }}
```

Comment: No, my question is specific to validation during `helm diff` command.

Comment: @jack_t, what version of helm are you using? I dont have a `diff` command.

Comment: I guess you are using this https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff

Comment: @jack_t, I guess diff does not do any kind of validation. It only shows you the diff. Apart from that in your question diff returned exist code 2 which is non-zero. You should treat it as error under normal circumstances.

Comment: Yes 'diff' is the helm plugin.

Comment: Exit code`2` is not an error. However, it means when there is a diff detected by `helm diff` it returns `2`. But this does not check if the changed K8s secret is deployable in K8s cluster.

Comment: If you want to really validate, you should use dry run potentially even with template and against the server. `helm template test mychart/ | kubectl apply --dry-run=server -f -` although this base64 error should also be captured with `dry-run=client`